# Adding additional scape_config to Google Managed Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, confluent-cloud

I'm not very familiar with Prometheus and I want to add scrape_config for Confluent Cloud metrics.

They have an integration for prometheus:

```
 scrape_configs:
  - job_name: Confluent Cloud
    scrape_interval: 1m
    scrape_timeout: 1m
    honor_timestamps: true
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - api.telemetry.confluent.cloud
    scheme: https
    basic_auth:
      username: <Cloud API Key>
      password: <Cloud API Secret>
    metrics_path: /v2/metrics/cloud/export
    params:
      "resource.kafka.id":
        - lkc-1
        - lkc-2
```

I'm using Google managed Prometheus in deployed in GKE and I want to add that config.
How can I add it?

Thanks

Comment: 1. This question being about configuration is probably off-topic here. 2. Even if it's on-topic I doubt it will be answered in it's current form: tag [google-managed-prometheus] has only 1 watcher, and I doubt there are many watchers of general Prometheus tag being familiar with Google's instance specifics. Consider maybe adding [google-kubernetes-engine].

Comment: @markalex, I think its on-topic but open to suggestions if you are familiar with a more suitable board. Thanks for the tag suggestion.

Comment: I believe [sf] or [devops.se] will be appropriate.

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags since `scrape_configs` is a general prometheus config, unrelated to GKE / Prometheus Operator. Also "managed" and "deployed in GKE" don't seem to go together. If you use [Prometheus Operator](https://prometheus-operator.dev/), then it has `additionalSrapeConfigs` section to add this